# Android studio unable to reference symbols in Room-runtime dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I'm trying to add Room data persistence to an Android project. For some reason, I'm not able to reference room-runtime classes.
[image: Cannot Resolve symbol]
Here's the most relevant part of my build.gradle. I've flipped between Room 2.3.4 and 2.0.0, trying to get symbols linking, but so far no luck.

```
def room_version = "2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-common:$room_version"
```

and the rest of the [build.gradle](https://gist.github.com/Alvtag/0a78a6a9064ab2689ee0db1b60cf17fd)

So, as you can see,

> import androidx.room.Database;

imports properly. I took a look at the project tab and see that room-common jar imports fine as a .jar, but room-runtime (where Room and RoomDatabase live) are .aar, and their symbols don't resolve:
[image: project tab]

In external libraries, room-runtime did get downloaded by gradle, but I can't reference its classes:
[image: room-runtime@ aar]

Any idea on how to fix this? I would have happy to provide more details and screenshots.

Comment: Try increasing the Room Version to 2.4.3 from 2.0.0 and  removing `implementation "androidx.room:room-common:$room_version"` then sync, then clean and then rebuild the project.

Comment: @MikeT thanks, but no luck.. this is what I see with that (after having invalidated caches and restarted too). https://imgur.com/a/F4j1zgG

Comment: from that screenshot you appear to have the room-common twice but you do not have room-compile (the one that you need)